# My API can't insert value with Gin Context

Tags: go

Could you help me or inform me what wrong with my code. I tried to make API for with GIN Framework. This is example of data and Post API

```
type Car struct {
    CarID string `json:"car_id"`
    Brand string `json:"brand"`
    Model string `json:"model"`
    Price int    `json:"price"`
}

var CarDatas = []Car{}

func CreateCar(ctx *gin.Context) {
    var newCar Car

    if err := ctx.ShouldBindJSON(&newCar); err != nil {
        ctx.AbortWithError(http.StatusBadRequest, err)
        return
    }

    newCar.CarID = fmt.Sprintf("c%d", len(CarDatas)+1)
    CarDatas = append(CarDatas, newCar)

    ctx.JSON(http.StatusCreated, gin.H{
        "car": newCar,
    })
}
```

This is my endpoint routes

```
func StartServer() *gin.Engine {
    router := gin.Default()

    router.POST("/cars", controllers.CreateCar)

    router.PUT("/cars/:carID", controllers.UpdateCar)

    router.GET("cars/:carID", controllers.GetCar)

    router.DELETE("cars/:carID", controllers.DeleteCar)
    return router
}
```

My question my code still bad request when insert a data. not respond just trying to POST

Do you have any clue?
Thanks for your time and the answer

[image]

I already check and fix formating and not really work. Please just guide me or give me a clue

Answer (score 2):

you using form-data on front end, then try using the following in Gin.

```
if err := c.Bind(&newCar); err != nil {
.....
}
```

ShouldBindJson should be used for json post requests.